# minSdk, targetSDK, Deprecated - Android

Tags: android, api

If my target API is 19, and my minimum is 8, in functions that say they were introduced in API 11 and enforce me to add this sort of attribute above the method: @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)

Will this method not work on API 8 phones?

However, if the method says deprecated, it will work on all phones? So if I'm choosing between deprecated and introduced in API 11, I should choose deprecated really? But if I was willing to do a little more work I could check phone API and run the method suited for that phone? Either that, or change my minimum API from 8 to 11? To see what my minSDK should be, should I test my code with target API set low, and if it causes errors, set my minSdk above that (or address the errors..either/or)?

Can people with Android phones update their API level? I don't have an Android and a quick Google didn't reveal this.

"Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the above size groups are deprecated and you should instead use the swdp configuration qualifier to define the smallest available width required by your layout resources. " - Does this mean you should use swdp **IF** you either check their phone is above API12 first, or you set your minSDK to 13?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Will this method not work on API 8 phones?

If by "this method" you mean "the method you called, that was added in API Level 11, that triggered the need for `@TargetApi`", then, yes, that method will not work on API Level 8, 9, or 10. It was added in API Level 11 and did not exist prior to that.

> However, if the method says deprecated, it will work on all phones?

Generally speaking, yes. The majority of deprecated methods are marked as deprecated because there is a better solution. Some methods are deprecated and also altered to do nothing, either for security reasons or because they simply could not support them any longer. Those are usually noted as such in the JavaDocs.

> So if I'm choosing between deprecated and introduced in API 11, I should choose deprecated really?

Ideally, you choose to use both, using `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to determine what API level you are running on. The API Level 11+ approaches are often richer and more in line with user expectations than are their deprecated counterparts. So, use the newer APIs when you can, and gracefully degrade to the older APIs (deprecated or not) when you have to.

> But if I was willing to do a little more work I could check phone API and run the method suited for that phone?

Yes, via `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`. See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html#Versions.

> Either that, or change my minimum API from 8 to 11?

That would be another possibility.

> To see what my minSDK should be, should I test my code with target API set low, and if it causes errors, set my minSdk above that (or address the errors..either/or)?

Generally, you choose your minimum SDK level based upon markets. Right now, [very few devices run API Level 8 or 9, and not that many run API Level 10](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). You might decide that it may not be worth the effort for testing the older devices.

> Can people with Android phones update their API level?

Device manufacturers sometimes release updates, and some users may turn to ROM mods, like Cyangenmod, to upgrade beyond what the manufacturer does.

> I don't have an Android

I would not go too far in Android development without purchasing a device. The emulators, while nice, are only emulators.

Answer (score 0):

The `@TargetAPI` annotation does nothing more than hiding the errors you get when using methods that require an API higher than X on a device with a lower API level:

> Indicates that Lint should treat this type as targeting a given API level, no matter what the project target is.

Deprecated methods usually have become obsolete because their are better solutions *in the new API levels*. These new methods don't exist yet in the older levels, so you'll have to go with the deprecated methods for those devices. Using a simple if statement to check what API level the user is using, you can select the appropriate method.

Lastly, some devices are too old and will not get updates anymore. Therefore, their API level will not change.